# How to Obfuscate my web application project.war using Ant & YGuard?

Tags: ant, obfuscation, yguard

We developed a web application (struts 1.x/Hibernate based) for which I built a 
war file using ANT build script. Now, my company wants me to obfuscate the .classes files 
before generating a war & distributing it to the client. When I googled, I came 
across [an example using YGuard](http://christiansons.net/mike/blog/2009/02/obfuscating-a-webapp-war-file-with-yguard-and-ant/) library to accomplish this task. The link was pretty useful however, I only had a partial success, as it obfuscated all the java classes, leaving behind the hibernate mapping (*.hbm.xml) files un-obfuscated, which had references to these classes which were already obfuscated.

For example: After obfuscation, references to MenuGlobalBean.class would turn to something like say A.B.H.I.N(where A,B..are package names & N is the class name). 
But my MenuGlobal.hbm.xml still refers to this as

```
<class name="com.mycompany.myproduct.bean.MenuGlobalBean" table="MENU_GLOBAL">
```

rather than

```
<class name="A.B.H.I.N" table="MENU_GLOBAL">
```

**Now my question is how do I obfuscate my war file in such a way that 
the obfuscated class references reflect in my *.hbm.xml & other config/property files if any.**

Below is my complete ANT build script using YGuard library for obfuscation

```
<!-- Build MyProject.war section -->
<project name="MyProject" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <property name="proj-home" value="/home/simba/tomcat-7.0.19/webapps/MyProject" />
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="WEB-INF/src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="lib" location="WEB-INF/lib"/>
  <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <path id="project-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${proj-home}/WEB-INF/lib" includes="*.jar" />
  </path>

  <target name="copy-non-java-files">
    <copy todir="build" includeemptydirs="false">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="*" />
            <include name="css/**/*" />
            <include name="help_files/**/*" />
            <include name="images/**/*" />
            <include name="js/**/*" />
            <include name="jsp/**/*" />
            <include name="schemas/**/*" />
            <include name="Sounds/**/*" />
            <include name="VideoImage/**/*" />
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/src" />
            <exclude name="yguard.jar" />
            <exclude name="*.war" />
            <exclude name="build.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="WEB-INF/classes/**/*" />
            <include name="WEB-INF/classes/*.xml" />
            <include name="WEB-INF/lib/**/*" />
            <include name="WEB-INF/*.xml" />
            <include name="WEB-INF/*.properties"/>
            <include name="WEB-INF/*.dtd" />
            <include name="WEB-INF/*.tld" />
            <include name="WEB-INF/*.txt" />
            <include name="WEB-INF/*.ico" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="clean,init,copy-non-java-files" description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}/WEB-INF/classes" classpathref="project-classpath"/>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile"
        description="generate the distribution" >
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <war jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyProject.war" basedir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
        description="clean up" >
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>




<!-- Using Yguard to obfuscate my .war file --> 
<!-- prepare a temporary directory in which the war file is expanded and obfuscated -->
<tempfile property="unwar.dir" destdir="${java.io.tmpdir}" deleteonexit="no"/>
<mkdir dir="${unwar.dir}"/>
<unwar src="${dist}/lib/MyProject.war" dest="${unwar.dir}"/>


<!-- create a jar of webapp classes (required by yguard) for obfuscation -->
<jar destfile="${unwar.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/MyProject.jar" whenempty="fail">
    <zipfileset dir="${unwar.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" excludes="*.xml,*.properties"/>
</jar>
<delete dir="${unwar.dir}/WEB-INF/classes/*" excludes="*.xml,*.properties"/>

<!-- create a fileset of internal libraries to be obfuscated -->
<fileset dir="${unwar.dir}/WEB-INF/lib" id="internal.lib.set">
    <include name="MyProject.jar"/>
</fileset>

<!-- move the internal libraries to a temporary directory and make a fileset out of them -->
<tempfile property="obfuscation.dir" destDir="${java.io.tmpdir}" deleteonexit="yes"/>
<mkdir dir="${obfuscation.dir}"/>
<move todir="${obfuscation.dir}">
    <fileset refid="internal.lib.set"/>
</move>

<!-- create a jar of web.xml (required by yguard) for obfuscation -->
<jar destfile="${obfuscation.dir}/web.xml.jar" whenempty="fail">
    <zipfileset dir="${unwar.dir}/WEB-INF" includes="*.xml"/>
</jar>

<!--<delete file="${unwar.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml"/> -->

<!-- make a fileset of all jars to be obfuscated -->
<fileset dir="${obfuscation.dir}" includes="*.jar" id="in-out.set"/>

<!-- make a fileset of the remaining libraries, these are not obfuscated -->
<path id="external.lib.path">
    <fileset dir="${unwar.dir}/WEB-INF/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>

<taskdef name="yguard"
    classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask"
    classpath="../ref/yguard.jar"/>

<yguard>
    <inoutpairs>
        <!-- these filesets are inputs to be obfuscated -->
        <fileset refid="in-out.set"/>
    </inoutpairs>
    <externalclasses refid="external.lib.path"/>  <!-- external libs, not obfuscated -->
    <rename>
        <adjust replaceContent="true">
            <include name="web.xml"/>  <!-- modified to reference the obfuscated Servlet -->
            <include name="struts-config.xml"/>
            <include name="*.hbm.xml"/>
        </adjust>
        <keep>
            <!-- classes, packages, methods, and fields which should not obfuscated are specified here -->
        </keep>
    </rename>
</yguard>
<!-- move our newly obfuscated classes back into the lib area -->
<move todir="${unwar.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
    <fileset dir="${obfuscation.dir}" includes="*_obf.jar"/>
</move>

<!-- unjar the adjusted web.xml --> 
<unzip dest="${unwar.dir}/WEB-INF/" src="${unwar.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/web.xml_obf.jar">
    <patternset includes="*.xml"/>
</unzip>
<!-- <delete>
    <fileset dir="${unwar.dir}/WEB-INF/lib" includes="web.xml*.jar"/>
</delete> -->

<!-- rebuild the war file -->
<war destfile="MyProject_obf.war" basedir="${unwar.dir}"/>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the same trick I used to encrypt the references in web.xml -- temporarily put the Hibernate .xml files into a jar. (See the section commented by "create a jar of web.xml (required by yguard) for obfuscation".)